# C# add formula in a cell programatically

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working with ***Visual Studio 9*** and I'm using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** to handle Excel files from a program

To add a formula in a cell I use

`xlWorkSheet.Cells[cwrite, j + 2].Formula = " =SUM(B" + cwrite.ToString() + "; 3)";`

Note the **space** between **"** and **=**

In This case, the formula displayed in the right cell, but is not executed, due to space

However, if I suppress the space

`xlWorkSheet.Cells[cwrite, j + 2].Formula = "=SUM(B" + cwrite.ToString() + "; 3)";`

I got the error **Error: Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Line: System.Dynamic**

Any Clue??

Thanks

David

Comment: Have you checked that the function you're trying to write to that cell actually works in Excel?

Comment: Logically, you have written just bad expression as mentioned by @greenjaed

Comment: The formula is Ok, actually updating the cell taking of the space it's work.